# Антоним функции $(document).ready которая будет выполнять до того когда загрузиться DOM?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть функция `$(document).ready` которая выполняет после того когда DOM структура загрузиться. А есть функция которая будет выполнять до того когда загрузиться DOM?

**UPD** Просили рассказать в чем именно проблема заключается.

У меня есть кнопочка онлайн консультация. Со своими стилями. Процесс загрузки идет такой.
1) Загружается страница, и начинает загружаться формочка онлайн консультация со стилями.
2) Скрипт который отвечает за расположении кнопочки внизу страницы, надпись на кнопке и других атрибутов срабатывает после полной загрузке DOM

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){


    $('#slick-6').dcSlick({
            location: 'bottom',
            align: 'right',
            offset: '100px',
            speed: 'fast',
            tabText: 'Онлайн консультация',
            autoClose: true
    });
});
</script
```

Проблема заключается в том, что есть секунда когда загружается форма, и устанавливаются параметры в скрипте, тем самым виден не очень приятный эффект. Т.е. форма расползается на весь экран, а когда скрипт устанавливает значение после всей загрузки dom форма устанавливается нормально. В связи с этим и возник данный вопрос. Может быть есть другие решения?

Comment: подключать js в самом верху страницы и без всяких оберток начинать что-то делать. Скрипт начнет работать, когда ДОМ еще не будет полностью создан, но не обязательно. Вполне может успеть создаться ДОМ.

Comment: Без всяких оберток? это как?

Comment: Просто начинаете что-то делать. Не такого события, которое Вы хотите.

Comment: хм) и что же начать делать? я даже незнаю( или я вас неправильно понимаю

Comment: Лучше расскажите какую конкретно задачу Вы хотите решить. Вам подскажут как это сделать правильно.

Comment: @ReinRaus Обновил вопрос! Спасибо!

Comment: просто скройте это _#slick-6_ элемент до того момента как он будет готов

Comment: Поясняю по поводу предыдущего комментария: надо установить элементу стиль `display: none` прямо в html-разметке - а в скрипте вызвать ему `show()`